# Master Bone to Move Entire Rig

Tags: rigging, parent

How can I set it so that the selected bone in the photo will move the entire rig with it? [image: Master Bone]
Essentially, the selected bone acts like a parent for all the bones in the rig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an IK setup, all of the IK controller bones and pole targets need to be parented to the 'master bone' at the base of the rig. e.g. [image]