# How do I make one bone that controls the entire rotation and movement of the armature? (or do I need to do that?)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, unity

[image]

I'm currently using Megaman from Legends to study rigging. The bone that I have selected above, I want to use to control the rotation and movement of the entire armature for animation. Now my question is this - **do I need a bone to control the rotation and position of the armature with a bone (and how do I do that?), or should I just control the rotation and position of the armature in object mode?**

**Please note:** I will be making a game (with a separate original character), so I will need the animation to transfer nicely into Unity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Master Bone to Move Entire Rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91813/master-bone-to-move-entire-rig)

Answer (score 1):

Using object mode would achieve the same effect. You might need to animate the character in Unity. The position and rotation gets imported too. You could still use a parent object or an offset animation.

If you need bones you can try disabling the deform checkbox and creating a control for the rig with constraints.